# Google Cloud Launcher Wordpress Site Times Out After VM Resize

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, google-compute-engine, firewall

I have a wordpress site which I created using Google Cloud Launcher. From what I can tell, this process created a VM and installed debian 8 with apache, php, and wordpress.

My site was running fine and I set up a custom domain. Then, Google suggested my instance was not large enough and I needed to resize the VM. They have a one click resize which I pressed. This moved my site to a new VM.

Now that I have moved to the new VM, when I type my site's URL into the address bar I just get a timeout error.

How can I begin to figure out what is wrong?

I tried restarting apache.  I also tried fetching my site using curl localhost after sshing to my VM and that works. I imagine this has something to do w/ a firewall or ip but I'm not sure where to start checking.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to resize the machine type for my Windows server based on Google's recommendation, resizing was done successfully without changing the external IP address since my VM was using a static IP. Instance IP address changes if using an Ephemeral IP.

At this point, I would verify if DNS A record is pointing to my current instance IP address.

Important: When resizing the VM as per Google's suggestion; It doesn't move to a new VM instead stops the instance, modifies the machine type, and restarts the instance. Find more information [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/viewing-sizing-recommendations-for-instances#resizing_instances_according_to_recommendations).